# show files in folders as options in kendo combobox

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown, kendo-combobox, kendo-datepicker

I need to make a form for my web page, able to deploy historical charts stored in a folder. Is it possible to make it read the elements inside the folder, and show them as options?

Example: an X folder, would contain 5 "region folders", each of these 5 folders would be an option for "region" item. Likewise, inside each of these "region folders" are at least another 4 "station folders", which in turn, would be options for "station" item, and so on... Finally there are differents charts for every day of every parameter of every station of every region.

Is it possible to do that? or any alternative to this? I leave an example of what I've done till now. Thanks in advance!

http://dojo.telerik.com/@rulo/apoSA/4

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. The data for each combobox in your example is specified in the datasource, for example you have this telerik web service:

```
read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Categories"
```

That url can be a web service or controller action on your server that returns the data. Assuming your web server has access to the charts folder you refer to, your server code can look at the files and sub folders within it and return data for the combobox derived from those folder and file names it finds.

I appreciate that this is not a definitive answer and it's not really possible to give one without knowing what server side technology you are using. I recommend working on this some more and then posting a new question if you need further help since your issue is really more server side than client side kendo.

If you intention is to read the local file system, as per your comment, then I believe that would prove difficult, if not impossible. Code running in the browser is sandboxed from the local file system for obvious security reasons.

Comment: actually I'm not intending to use a server. The one abobe was just an example, I have thought more in something like this, if it's possible:

     read: "C:\webpage\historico\metropolitana\Cerrillos"